# Can not get the next part of the PL/SQL while loop to work

Tags: sql, plsql

I have to create a while loop that goes 1+1=2..1+4=5..all the way too 4+4=8, I get the first part down but im stuck on what to do next.

```
 DECLARE 
 v_recno    testloop1.rec_no%TYPE :=1;
 v_ctr      testloop1.ctr%TYPE :=1;
 v_datain   testloop1.data_in%TYPE :=2;

 BEGIN
  WHILE v_recno = 1 AND v_ctr < 5 LOOP
  INSERT INTO testloop1(rec_no, ctr, data_in)
 VALUES(v_recno, v_ctr, v_datain);
 v_recno :=v_recno;
 v_ctr :=v_ctr + 1;
 v_datain :=v_recno + v_ctr;
 END LOOP;
END;
 /

 SQL> @ loop

  PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

     SQL> select * 
     2  from testloop1;
     REC_NO        CTR DATA_IN
    ---------- ---------- ----------
     1          1 2
     1          2 3
     1          3 4
     1          4 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve, you only need to wrap your loop inside an outer one. So one loop will iterate through v_recno (outer loop) from 1 ..4, and the other will iterate through  v_ctr (inner loop). Something like this (not tested):

```
DECLARE 
 v_recno    testloop1.rec_no%TYPE :=1;
 v_ctr      testloop1.ctr%TYPE :=1;
 v_datain   testloop1.data_in%TYPE :=1;    --change from 2 to 1

BEGIN
  WHILE v_recno < 5 LOOP
    WHILE v_ctr < 5 LOOP
     v_datain :=v_recno + v_ctr;       --Moved up before insert statement
     INSERT INTO testloop1(rec_no, ctr, data_in)
     VALUES(v_recno, v_ctr, v_datain);
     v_ctr :=v_ctr + 1;
    END LOOP;
   v_recno := v_recno + 1;
   v_ctr := 1;             --Added this to reset
  END LOOP;
END;
 /
```

Using basic loop:

```
DECLARE 
 v_recno    testloop1.rec_no%TYPE :=1;
 v_ctr      testloop1.ctr%TYPE :=1;
 v_datain   testloop1.data_in%TYPE :=1;

BEGIN
  LOOP
   LOOP
     v_datain :=v_recno + v_ctr;
     INSERT INTO testloop1(rec_no, ctr, data_in)
     VALUES(v_recno, v_ctr, v_datain);
     v_ctr :=v_ctr + 1;
     IF v_ctr > 4 THEN
         exit;
     END IF;
    END LOOP;
   v_recno := v_recno + 1;
   v_ctr := 1;
     IF v_recno > 4 THEN
         exit;
     END IF;      
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: that achieves what I received on my pl/sql same output it stops at the output1 4 5

Comment: @JeffMercier Update with *v_ctr := 1* and tested, It worked now :)

Comment: @JeffMercier The reason why it did not work before, because, v_ctr reached 5, and in the next outer iteration, will not enter the inner iteration because v_ctr is 5. So I just reset v_ctr before each outer iteration to 1.

Comment: @JeffMercier I also moved the line `v_datain :=v_recno + v_ctr;` up, before insert statement, and the default value of `v_datain = 1`

Comment: thanks this problem has been erking me for some time now.

Comment: @JeffMercier Welcom! You can accept my answer if it solved the problem :)

Comment: would it be possible for you to change it to a basic loop instead of while?

Comment: @JeffMercier by basic, you mean `FOR` loop?